# Is there a well known way to implement pagination with multiple RSS feeds?

Tags: java, rss, pagination

I'm utilizing multiple RSS feeds on my website and I'm reading them through Java ATOM and combining them to create a feed for the user. The issue I'm running into is performance. I'm pulling several different RSS feeds and I would like to implement a pagination on the feed but I don't know how to implement this when you are drawing from multiple RSS feeds.

NOTE: the feed is merged then sorted by date to display to the user.

Does anyone know of any well known design patterns for solving an issue like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try using first, previous, next and last as a link relation:

```
  <link rel="next" href="http://abc.org/catalogue.atom?page=1"/>
```

Defined in RFC 5005,  section 3(Feed Paging and Archiving).See here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005